# How to display a div when hovering over another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here my first div shows an image. If you mouse hover on the image then it should show another div named `hdiv`.

Here $pitem[6] return data from database with php for loop.

**CODE**

```
<div class="pcimga">
    <div class="pcimg"><img src="Portfolio_Image/'.$pitem[6].'" class="pcimg" /></div>

        <div class="hdiv" style="display:none;">
           <span class=" butnn"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal'.$pitem[0].'">View</a>
        </div>          
</div>
```

Comment: Incomplete info...! Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$('.pcimga').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.hdiv').show();
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.hdiv').hide();
});
```

**Check it here** [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n52H2/2/)

Comment: Your solution will work if you have only one instance with class `.pcimga`. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n52H2/1/)

Comment: Now it also works in case of multiple .pcimga divs. I'm wondering why u r using .closest('.pcimga') in ur code?

Comment: Plus, ur code doesn't hide the div when the mouse leaves

Comment: Yea, I have not provided mouseout handler.You don't need to wonder as I have binded event using `'.pcimg'` thus used `closeset`

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
.pgimga:hover~.hdiv
{
display:block;
}
```

let me know if you want any further guidance..

Comment: hdiv is not child, could be instead: `.pgimga:hover ~ .hdiv`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pure CSS:

**1. When** ***.hdiv***  **is next to**  ***.pcimg***

```
.pcimg:hover+.hdiv{
    display:block !important;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm6ee/)**

**2. When there is gap between** ***.hdiv***  **and**  ***.pcimg***

```
.pcimg:hover~.hdiv{
    display:block !important;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhzXa/)**

**Note : Internal styles have higher priority than External styles.So for giving External styles more priority `!important` is needed**

Answer (score 1):

Try this in CSS. You need to use !important to override the inline style "display:none"

```
.pcimg:hover+.hdiv
{
    display:inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with onmouseover and onmouseout events using jquery:

```
<div class="pcimga">
    <div class="pcimg"><img onmouseover='$(".hdiv").show();'  onmouseout='$(".hdiv").hide();' src="Portfolio_Image/'.$pitem[6].'" class="pcimg" /></div>

        <div class="hdiv" style="display:none;">
           <span class=" butnn"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal'.$pitem[0].'">View</a>
        </div>          
</div>
```

if you have multiple instances of this block, all of the images will be visible though. to distinguish which one is hovered you can send hideDiv(this) and get which image hovered to show appropriate image.